# How can I get a count from a PS command

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting

I have a powershell command:

```
Get-ADGroupMember -identity "CCVGHCFinReadOnly" -Recursive | foreach{ get-aduser -properties employeeid $_} | select SamAccountName,objectclass,name,employeeid | Export-Csv "C:\Temp\AD Membership\GovReadOnly.csv
```

This script works great to return members of AD groups.  I also want to add the count for auditing purposes.  So the script should list all ad users and then a count at the bottom.

Right now if I use | Measure it gives me a count but that is all I get.  So I can either get the actual users in the AD group OR the count.  How can I get both with this one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$members = Get-ADGroupMember ... | select SamAccountName,objectclass,name,employeeid

$members | Export-Csv "C:\Temp\AD Membership\GovReadOnly.csv"
@($members).Count | Add-Content "C:\Temp\AD Membership\GovReadOnly.csv"
```

Comment: Never thought of pumping the output to a variable then reading the var into the file and then counting the members.  This is simple and brilliant.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head side effects come to mind.  In this example I am incrementing a variable outside of the pipeline from within the pipeline.  I admit it feels kind of gross.  Maybe somebody else can suggest a solution that does not rely on this sort of side effect.

```
$count = 0
Get-ADGroupMember -identity "CCVGHCFinReadOnly" -Recursive `
| foreach { 
    $count++
    get-aduser -properties employeeid $_} `
| select SamAccountName,objectclass,name,employeeid `
| Export-Csv "C:\Temp\AD Membership\GovReadOnly.csv
```

Now you can do whatever you want with `$count`.

Comment: This works but I agree it just doesn't feel good.  I was doing something similar before I jumped over.  Thanks though!